# Giving style to h1 only if it's the first of its page when printing (CSS3)

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to give style to an h1 element only if it's at the top of its page when printing?
Is there a pseudo-class that applies to the first element of a page (maybe in the @page rule)? If not, can I get the same result with js?

Comment: I think, the example should answer your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. Can someone think of another way to achieve this?

Comment: Not in JS, because the print-dialog (where you specify the borders, page-size, orientation, etc) is system-dependent and did not return any value to JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, thank you. @steven